# Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2?(Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, arguments

There are many other similar questions to this one, but there is a lack of answers and they vary for each project.
I have this error
'Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2?'
But on the previous arrays that I used this error did not occur? it could be a problem with the code but i am unsure? I have went through searching for other errors that may influence it, but have had no luck.
Below is my coding,

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *menu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *section1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *section2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *section3;


@end

@implementation MenuViewController

@synthesize menu, section1, section2, section3;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.section1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"News Feed", @"Buy Shares", @"Sell Shares", nil];

    self.section2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Finances", @"Current Holdings", @"Trading History", nil];

    ***self.section3 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Leaderboard", nil];***

    self.menu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.section1, self.section2, self.section3, nil];


    [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:200.0f];
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftWidthLayout = ECFullWidth;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [self.menu count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if (section == 0) {

        return [self.section1 count];

    } else if (section == 1) {

        return [self.section2 count];

    } else if (section == 2) {

        return  [self.section3 count];

    }


}


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    if (section == 0) {

        return @"Stock Market";

    } else if (section == 1) {

        return @"Portfolio";

    } else if (section == 2) {

        return  @"Options";

    }


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {


        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {


        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }





    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

     */

    UIViewController *newTopViewController;


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    } else if (indexPath.section == 2) {

        NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.section3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];

    }




    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
        CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];


}

@end
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks. The error appears where i have placed '***'

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It would be easier for you to get the answer if you'd at least tagged your question with language name you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been nice if you had indicated which line was causing problems, but I think I found it anyway:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Leaderboard", nil];
```

`arrayWithObject` only expects an object, not a comma-separated array of objects. Use the following instead:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObject: @"Leaderboard"];
```

Or, to be more consistent with the surrounding code, use

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Leaderboard", nil];
```

Comment: sorry i was in the process of indicating, i didnt realise i forgot. Would your suggestion still work if i include more than one string?

Comment: @JasonTaylor I'm assuming you want to use `arrayWithObjects:` (note the 's') because that's what the lines above and below it use.

Comment: For more than one string, you would use arrayWithObjects (notice the s), just like you did on the 3 similar lines. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) is the documentation explaining the difference between the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Leaderboard", nil];

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).